# Internet explorer timeout while is waiting backend answer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I've a functionality that takes more than 5 minutes to generate a report. This functionality is fully optimized.

After this five minutes, Internet Explorer shows a timeout meanwhile the backend functionality remains working.

I've tried to made the requests using setInterval and setTimeout JavaScript functions. But after 5 minutes, the timeout Screen appears.

The tomcat configuration is standard, so, default value is 30minutes.

This functionality works properly in other web-Navigators, but the requirements demands to work in Internet Explorer.

Do you know how to avoid this timeout?

Comment: So where is the question?